# Update mysql with select clause as the updated value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, phpbb3

I try to copy a value from t2.f2 to t1.f1 namely, topics and posts tables of PHPbb3 forum. I have tried the following sql:

```
UPDATE t_topics SET
 topic_title = (SELECT t_posts.post_subject WHERE
  t_posts.post_id = t_topics.topic_first_post_id)
WHERE topic_id = 2;
```

I have got the following error:

> MySQL said:
>
> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE t_posts.post_id = t_topics.topic_first_post_id) WHERE
>   topic_id = 2' at line 1

How could I achive this using sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `from` clause:

```
UPDATE t_topics
    SET topic_title = (SELECT t_posts.post_subject
                       FROM t_posts
                       WHERE t_posts.post_id = t_topics.topic_first_post_id
                      )
    WHERE topic_id = 2;
```

Comment: Oh It is my mistake, I may realized that regarding the name of the table before the field is going to be sufficient. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just I need a little extra hint, Does it enough sufficient to remove the last WHERE to run this query over all the `topics` table? It is sensitive data in the forum and I afraid to destroy it.

Comment: It is always good to test `update` and `delete` queries on copies of the data before trying them on real data -- or at least stashing copies of the table somewhere so you can easily recover.  But yes, removing the `where` should have the desired effect of doing the lookup for all topics.  Do note that it will return `NULL` if no match is found.